# How to tersely run a globally installed Node.js app

Tags: node.js, shell, node-modules

I was recently using [mongo-express](https://github.com/andzdroid/mongo-express) which is written in Node.js. I've installed it globally following instructions on their GitHub page. It says in order to run it:

```
cd YOUR_PATH/node_modules/mongo-express/ && node app.js
```

I was wondering if there's any workarounds to avoid changing directory to the app's folder first (using cd).
By the way, in [npm's doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders), it says

> When in global mode, executables are linked into {prefix}/bin on Unix.

In my case (using mac), executable `app.js` *is* linked into `/usr/local/bin`. But if I just type `app.js` in the command line trying to run it, it'd say `-bash: /usr/local/bin/app.js: Permission denied`. Even if this works, wouldn't `app.js` be a too generic name and become conflicted with other apps later?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: You can use [dtruss](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtruss.1m.html) to see what permission you are missing when running `app.js`.